# How do I get a full list of all firebase emulator function logs?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I have looked everywhere for a way to make firebase function logs viewable in its entirety (it seems they are truncated). It only shows the last few lines. Is there any way to expand this or at the very least get a file where the logs are being pulled from so I can view them in its entirety?

[image: Scrolling issue]

By request I have added a screenshot, however the text is is not pertinent to the question. The crux of my question is that I would like to scroll back to the beginning of these logs, see scrollbar to the right. The reason for this is that sometimes the code throws an error, as we know errors are long and I can only see the error partially because it ends up being truncated.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you please post a simple, clear screenshot along with your code that logs these? The current GIF is too blurry.

Comment: I have added an edit to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Yes this is absolutely infuriating to me. I can't actually see the line that describes the error I'm getting in the emulator because it cuts off all but the last several lines of a lengthy stack trace. Truly boneheaded design decision.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the full output of the logs in my terminal, if I start the emulators from the CLI.